# faye working with rails3 app please help!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, faye

I am trying to get faye running on my production server but what do i use in the javascript_include_tag to get the faye.js file ?

In development i use this :

```
http://localhost:9292/faye.js
```

But in production it does not work. Something like this ? or ... ?

```
http://www.mysite.com/faye.js
```

I am using apachi for the rest of my site and thin for faye.   Do i need to configure something in apachi to send to thin / faye ?

very confussed.

Plese help.

best regards
Richard

Comment: did you try http://www.mysite.com:9292/faye.js? Or are you running both servers on the same port...

Comment: if i go to that url i get my catch all rails page where no other route has matched.    should i be adding a route for faye into routes file or should it not even de getting into here.   do i need to chnage apache conf to point to thin server somehow ? thanks

Comment: You should set up thin client and apache on different ports. Ensure apache is running under port 80 and thin is using port 9292. (You should see the port being used when you start each server)

Comment: its was my firewall blocking that port!!  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thin and Apache need to be set up running on different ports.

The default settings for both should work, but you should double check. Ensure apache is running under port 80 and thin is using port 9292. These numbers should be visible when the servers start up.

In the end you should be able to access faye.js at http://mysite.com:9292/faye.js and your site at http://mysite.com/

NOTE: Turned my comments into an answer.