# How to enable thin server for faye in production in rails3 for private_pub gem with apache2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, faye, private-pub

I am using `private_pub` gem for live chat in my `rails 3.2` application and it is working perfectly on development mode but I am stuck at how to do it on production.

I am using `apache2` in production. When I ran this command on server

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production`

It starts the `thin` server but my app keeps on waiting for response from

`http://www.example.com:9292/faye.js`

It doesn't do anything. I am unable to connect with `faye` in prodution

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Thin and Apache need to be set up running on different ports.
>
> The default settings for both should work, but you should double
>   check. Ensure apache is running under port 80 and thin is using port
>   9292. These numbers should be visible when the servers start up.
>
> In the end you should be able to access faye.js at
>   http://yoursite.com:9292/faye.js and your site at http://yoursite.com/

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667347/539075